# problem building TensorFlow r1.13 from sources

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to build under Ubuntu 18.04 TensorFlow r1.13 from sources and whichever compatible version of bazel I use I get the same errors:

```
ERROR: /home/hamlatzis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hamlatzis/bc20d0623a1a0c4eaa510688c26216cb/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/protobuf/closure_proto_library.bzl:66:21: name 'ProtoInfo' is not defined (did you mean 'protos'?)
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'closure/protobuf/closure_proto_library.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'closure/protobuf/closure_proto_library.bzl' has errors
```

I need to be on r1.13, but to be on the safe side I've tried with other branches (r1.14 and master) and had no problems with those

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different Bazel version.

[Bazel 0.21.0](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.21.0) worked for me for Tensorflow r1.13.